# How to create a checkbox control with a text inside via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to create a `checkbox` control with a text inside via jQuery?

[image]

The following code doesn't work as expected (I think this is because the `input` tag is self-closing):

```
let autorefreshCheckbox = $('<input/>', {
    type: 'checkbox',
    html: 'Autorefresh'
});
$('#some-id').append(autorefreshCheckbox);
```

What can I do then?

Comment: You should specify better what do you want to obtain...

Comment: whats the error you are getting?

Comment: `input` does not have `innerhtml`.

Comment: @Rejith R Krishnan Ok. What can I do then?

Comment: @squaleLis Ok, edited.

Comment: You need to show this label after the checkbox?

Comment: @Rejith R Krishnan Yes

Comment: Wrap the `checkbox` within the `label`.

Comment: @John R Yeah, I know, but how can I do it via jQuery?

Comment: Why with JQuery? you can just use Javascript for that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var autorefreshCheckbox = $('<input/>', {
    type: 'checkbox'
}).prependTo('<label>Autorefresh</label>').parent();
$('#some-id').append(autorefreshCheckbox);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="some-id"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want to achieve:

```js
$(function() {
  var autorefreshCheckbox = $('<input/>', {
      type: 'checkbox',
      id: 'check'
  });
  
  $('#some-id').append(autorefreshCheckbox);
  $('#some-id').append($('<label for="check">Autorefresh</label>'));
});
```

```html
 <div id="some-id"></div>
```

It is not possible to insert HTML inside an input-element.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var autorefreshLabel = $('<label>Autorefresh</label>')
var autorefreshCheckbox = $('<input/>', { type: 'checkbox' });
autorefreshLabel.append(autorefreshCheckbox);
$('body').append(autorefreshLabel);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/qqE1jguC4SkLYC9z3nHn?p=preview

Comment: Sorry, text should be after the checkbox. Is it possible?

Comment: Ye, sure, you just should use prepend method instead append. Fixed my plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/qqE1jguC4SkLYC9z3nHn?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hemal_301080/cwx8d06w/)**

```
$("#container").append("<input type=checkbox />" + YOUR_TEXT_VARIABLE);
```

Comment: I need to change that text dynamically every 1 second. How can I do it then?

Comment: You can put a dynamic variable for the text.

Comment: What should I do the next time I need to change this text? Call `append` again? Will it work correctly?

Comment: If you need to change text for the same checkbox, then you can place text in any HTML element, and then select that element and change it.